# How do CPU, IOMMU and DMA controller interact with each other?

Tags: cpu, dma, intel

While drawing an interaction diagram involving CPU, IOMMU and DMA controller, I failed to find any authentic document showing how they interact with each other. Is the DMA controller physically a separate unit from the IOMMU, or do they reside on the same chip? Does Intel support IOMMU operation?

Comment: Under *Intel* you meant exactly what? Intel SoCs (many of them nowadays) support IOMMU. The DMA controller can be part of any block, but usually MMU is MMU and doesn't involve DMA per se. The three you listed are orthogonal to each other. They may be present in all possible combinations depending on the actual chip. (Is it about electrical engineering?)